# Is it possible to manage state in multiple copies of the same component?

Tags: reactjs

I am creating a feedback form to track the performance of workers' files. To do this I want to be able to include comments on what may have been wrong about the file. I created a component called CommentBox that I want to utilize on all questions.

```
import React from "react";
const CommentBox = (props) => {
  return (<textarea>
      name={props.name}
      id={props.name}
      cols="200"
      rows="2"
      onChange={props.onChange}
    ></textarea>
  );
};
export default CommentBox;
```

I want to manage the state of this component inside the parent component, which currently is a list of questions. The trouble I'm having is that each of these questions will have a CommentBox component. I therefore end up changing the state of the component each time I type in a new box, which would mean I can only get feedback on one of these per page.

Here's how I put together the state and event handler:

```
const [comment, setComment] = useState("");

  const handleCommentChange = (e) => {
    setComment(e.target.value);
  };
```

Would I need to set up a different state for each question that uses the comment box? Or is there a way to use props that I'm not seeing?

TIA!

Comment: You could initialize the state variable as an array and push new comments to it.

Comment: This is awesome! Thank you so much. Should make life a bit easier